# getDrawable (int) in Context cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)

Tags: java, android

Here's the code:

```
String id = "R.drwable.br" + mQuestionNumber;
mSlikaNastavi.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(id));
```

> error found on getDrawable(id): getDrawable (int) in Context cannot be
>   applied to (java.lang.String)

`mSlikaNstavi` is `ImageView`, and I would like to change image from java. I cant write in `R.drawable.br2` in `getDrwable()` because every time `mQuestionNumber` is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have drawables like br1, br2, br3,... and you think that by concatenating R.drawable.br and mQuestionNumber you get the id of the drawable but this is not the case.

do this:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("br" + mQuestionNumber, "drawable", getPackageName());
mSlikaNastavi.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(id));
```

Answer (score 1):

A drawable Id needs to be `int` rather than `String`. You can get the relative `int` Id using `getIdentifier()`

**Instead of**

`mSlikaNastavi.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(id))`

**Use**

```
String id = "br" + mQuestionNumber;
mSlikaNastavi.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier(id, "drawable", getPackageName())));`
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but: https://imgur.com/a/aumHnRe

Comment: @Manuelbradičić check the updated the answer

Comment: Android app is crashing when it comes on this part of code. When I comment this part of code it does not.

Comment: @Manuelbradičić spelling of drawable was incorrect. check the udpated answer

Comment: `String id = "R.drawable.br" + mQuestionNumber;` should  be `String id = "br" + mQuestionNumber;`

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to extract the Drawable Id by passing your own id value, instead of the ids which are present in R.java

So for that getIdentifier method is used where you need to provide the drawable name, type of the resource which is "drawable" in your case, and the packageName where Android will search the drawable from.

```
    int drawableId = getResources().getIdentifier("br" + mQuestionNumber,"drawable",getPackageName());
```

After the id is found, use it to show it in imageView using setImageDrawable() and as it required Drawable get the Drawabel from its iD using getDrawable() passing in the ID.

```
    mSlikaNastavi.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(drawableId));
```

So the code is:

```
    int drawableId = getResources().getIdentifier("br" + mQuestionNumber,"drawable",getPackageName());
    mSlikaNastavi.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(drawableId));
```